# Can't install ruby on rails in ubuntu gnome 15.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I am trying to install ruby on rails. I'm at version 2.3.0 for `ruby` and `gem` version of 2.5.1.

When I run the command `gem install rails` I get an error that says:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)     You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0 directory.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I guess you are using the ruby system. You have to be sudo to install gems. Have you tried to use rvm / rbenv to install ruby. Gems are stored in your user folder (therefore no sudo right needed).

Comment: I recommend using rvm too (see my answer) and btw stay on LTS versions of ubuntu (14.04, 16.04, 18.04, ...).

Answer (score 0):

`gem install` tries to put files in "system-wide" directories. These are protected, such that only the `root` user can write into.

You have at least three possibilities:

- `sudo gem install ...`, this will write the gem files into /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
- `gem install --user-install`, this will install the gem "locally" in your users home directory
- `apt-get install ruby-rails` (not sure about the package name), which will install the ruby on rails version maintained by your distributions maintainers (Canonical).
- *install and use `rvm`* or `rbenv` (and there might be other options). Afterwards `gem install` will usually just work and install the gems **for your user only**

While the `rvm` setup might be a tiny bit confusing for newbies, I recommend using that approach. It will make updating and installing ruby, gems and different versions of it really easy.